# Does disposing a JFrame cause memory leakage?

Tags: java, swing, memory, memory-leaks, jframe

I am writing a test program as follows:

1. When a user clicks button A, it opens 50 JFrames.
2. When the user clicks button B it disposes all JFrames shown by clicking button A.

I find that the memory does not decrease after clicking button B. I determined this using the Task Manager, <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>del</kbd> in Windows, and checking the memory usage of "java".

Comment: Some code will help us definitely...

Comment: See [Remove Top-Level Container on Runtime](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6309407/remove-top-level-container-on-runtime/6310284#6310284).

Comment: My code is nothing special.
Creating JFrame by new JFrame.
Dispose it by calling dispose()

Comment: Also, don't forget that Garbage Collection occurs only when needed, not right after you have disposed of objects. Finally, make sure that your code doesn't retain references to the 50 frames that were just disposed.

Comment: @jfpoilpret  thanks for valuable input

Answer (score 11, accepted):

That's right, no way, not able to solve that (not only in Java PL),

1) really don't create lots of [Top-Level Containers](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/toplevel.html) on Runtime/Fly, because they are never finalized, and until current JVM instance exits, and these Object never been GC'ed only their `Grapfics2D`

2) `myContainer#dispose()` on Runtime is same for current JVM instance as `myContainer#setVisible(false)` in connections with JVM available and used Memory

3) create only few `Top-Level Containers` (maximum simultaneously displayed ), re-use that, but put there [JPanel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6309407/remove-top-level-container-on-runtime) as 1.st `JComponent` and call `myPanel#removeAll()`, otherwise you'll remove [RootPane](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/rootpane.html) and from your Container stays only Borders :-) would be translucent

4) partialy is possible to reduce JVM used Memory by call GC, but just returs amount from `Graphics2D` and `Garbage` doesn't works immediatelly,

5) more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6309407/remove-top-level-container-on-runtime) usefull info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6294184/determine-how-much-top-level-containers-are-opened)

Comment: btw, do Java knows the problem?

Comment: @Bear you have two choises 1) create three - four Top-Level Containers, 1st. would be JFrame other JDialog(with Modality too) or JWindow, 2) or look for CardLayout http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html and then switch betweens Cards instead of create Top-Level Containers :-)

Comment: @Bear btw, do Java knows the problem?, did you ever seen buch of Windows that produced from another aplication, as I said not Java rellated issue, beacuse Top-Level Containers comings from Native OS, just their contens is from concreted Programing Language

Answer (score 2):

Without any code we can't help you much... are you calling jFrame.[dispose()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/awt/Window.html#dispose%28%29)?

> public void dispose()
>
> Releases all of the native screen resources used
>   by this Window, its subcomponents, and all of its owned children. That
>   is, the resources for these Components will be destroyed, any memory
>   they consume will be returned to the OS, and they will be marked as
>   undisplayable.

More information available [here](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/awt/Window.html#dispose%28%29)

Answer (score 0):

If there is a strong reference to GC(garbage collector) root from your frame, then if you called dispose method, it does not get garbage collected, so you can't see any memory changes after you dispose all of the frames. If you want memory, from stuff that you should release, then you need to garbage collect the frames.